# BQ Aquaris Ubuntu ed SIM cards not recognized anymore

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris, bq

I have been using a BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu edition for almost a year and had no problem with it. I never tweaked it in any way (unless you consider updating with OTA a tweak) but two weeks ago, I decided to change the SIM card in use for data (as I often had done already) and it deactivated my SIM cards (as always) but never reactivated them. I thought the problem was a SIM card problem since I had done nothing unusual to my phone (not even updating) before the problem happened so I bought a new SIM card which arrived today (the other one is still in the post office) and when I plugged it in, the phone didn't recognize it. Also, I don't have any wifi either : everything network related is now under an "indicator-network" menu in the task bar (when you swipe from up to down).
I checked Google before coming: similar problems occur when people tweak their phone (to install android for example) and accidentally wipe their IMEI number but as I said, I did not tweak it and I checked: calling *#06# returned two IMEI numbers, one for each SIM card.
What can I do ?

Thanks for any help you can bring,

Benjamin

P.S: Excuse me if I did any mistake while writing, I'm not native…

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so have you tried the new (and) old SIM in another phone? I found that sometimes on my tablet the wi-fi/data can fail to come back on when I turn it to flight mode and then back again to save battery. Have you tried turning the flight mode back on and of a few times?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I had a little bit dropped the issue for a long moment since i had other priorities. I have solved it yesterday by reinitalizing the phone to factory settings (System settings → Reinitalize or something like this...) but turning on and off flight mode didn't do anything at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it yesterday by reinitalizing the phone to factory settings (System settings → Reinitalize or something like this...)
Now my SIM cards are both recognized and my carrier providers are happy because I paid a lot for SIM cards which I didn't need :|